# Unable to find nuget folder

Tags: nuget

I'm unable to find some nuget packages (VS 2019, asp.net core 2.2). I found that System.ComponentModels.Annotations can't be found in my .nuget folder and in VS, there is no "expand" arrow next to it like all the other packages:

[image]

In my .nuget folder:

[image]

I've tried clearing out my packages folder and re-building to get all the packages. I've tried update-package -reinstall. I've tried Installing system.componentmodel.annotations directly (rather than having it install as a dependency).  My solution builds fine, but I can't find this package anywhere on my harddrive.  I've also noticed that Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design is exhibiting the exact same behavior.

Comment: is not being able to find the package causing an error? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to run a gulp script that run a powershell script.  This script loads types I need in order to run a class serializer on certain classes.  As such, I need to load DLLs and their dependencies.  I'm trying to load the nuget DLLs from their packages as I know where they are both on my desktop and up in my CI/CD pipeline. However, I'm running into issues because I can't find these DLLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When NuGet restores a project that uses `PackageReference` for packages (all SDK-style projects, and opt-in for traditional projects), it writes the `obj\project.assets.json` file, which is what MSBuild uses to complete the rest of the build.

Looking at the `packageFolders` section of my test project, I see this:

```
  "packageFolders": {
    "c:\\git\\test\\globalPackages\\": {},
    "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\NuGetFallbackFolder": {}
  },
```

note that I have a `nuget.config` that redirects my global packages folder away from my user profile global packages folder, so temporary/fake packages I create don't pollute my real dev environment. FYI in case you're wondering why you don't see `c:\users\zivkan\.nuget\packages`.

But notice that there are two package folders.

Looking for `System.ComonentModel.Annotations` in the `libraries` section of `project.assets.json`, I see:

```
    "System.ComponentModel.Annotations/4.5.0": {
      "sha512": "UxYQ3FGUOtzJ7LfSdnYSFd7+oEv6M8NgUatatIN2HxNtDdlcvFAf+VIq4Of9cDMJEJC0aSRv/x898RYhB4Yppg==",
      "type": "package",
      "path": "system.componentmodel.annotations/4.5.0",
      "files": [
          // list of every file in package
      ]
    },
```

see the path says `system.componentmodel.annotations/4.5.0`, which means it could be in either or both of `c:\git\test\globalPackages\system.componentmodel.annotations\4.5.0` and/or `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.componentmodel.annotations\4.5.0`.

For your use-case of trying to load it in Powershell, you can try to load one of the assemblies in the `lib\*` directory. Pick a TFM you think is compatible with your version of Powershell.

As for the reason that Solution Explorer doesn't have a twisty to expand the package, go find the package in the `targets` section of the `project.assets.json` and you'll see this:

```
      "System.ComponentModel.Annotations/4.5.0": {
        "type": "package",
        "compile": {
          "ref/netcoreapp2.0/_._": {}
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netcoreapp2.0/_._": {}
        }
      },
```

In other words, the package is not bringing in any assets or additional NuGet dependencies. Therefore nothing to expand in Solution Explorer.

In this specific case it's because `netcoreapp2.0` has the assembly built-in to the runtime, and the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` package has the compile-time metadata for it. This is why I asked why you are looking for the package. If you use `project.assets.json` to find the exact `System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll` that the build uses during compile, you'll find a metadata-only reference assembly that can't be loaded. But I gave insturations above on how to find the package directory and you can look for a loadable dll in one of the `lib\*` directories to try to load in Powershell.